# How can I exclude all .local domains from LastPass?

Tags: lastpass

We use LastPass as our password manager in our team. We also have decided to use `.local` as our development TLD.

Thus we would use these domains for example:

```
project.local
db.project.local
admin.project.local
accounts.project.local
```

or

```
another-project.local
db.another-project.local
learner.another-project.local
teacher.another-project.local
```

Every time we login into any of these domains, LastPass's extension offers us to save the password, and each time we tell it to not do it for that domain, and every time it asks again and again.

We tried to add `*.local` to account settings, but it seems that it does not support wildcards for domain names.

What should we do?

Comment: Have your checked LastPass documentation? Also LastPass had proven they are insecure and you should seriously consider switching to a different password manager.